# How can I custom draw each tile on treemap squarified chart

Tags: angular, highcharts

I need to draw this chart like this picture: 
[image]

I also need to display nested data. When you click a cell other data is displayed.

I have been reading the doc and searched in google but I couldn't find any solution. This is how I'm drawing the chart right now

I'm using "order" field to fill each tile value. I'm close to get the final result but the second and third tile are fitting like in different way I need.

https://jsfiddle.net/elefantelimpio/vmt4nLp5/11/

```
const highChartOptions = {
    colorAxis: {
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        drillUpButton: {
            position: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -10,
                y: 10
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'treemap',
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            animationLimit: 1000,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            levelIsConstant: false,
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                borderWidth: 3
            }],
            turboThreshold: 100000,
            data: [],
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.realValue || this.point.value;
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
};

data.forEach((motivator, index) => {
            motivadorPoint = {
                id: motivator._id,
                name: motivator._id,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[index],
                realValue: motivator.count,
                value: motivator.order
            };

      motivator.employees.forEach(employee => {
                employeePoint = {
                    id: employee,
                    name: `${employee.name} ${employee.lastName1} ${employee.lastName2}`,
                    parent: motivator._id,
                    value: 10
                };
                highChartOptions.series[0].data.push(employeePoint);
            });

            highChartOptions.series[0].data.push(motivadorPoint);
        });

Highcharts.chart('container', highChartOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the **SliceAndDice** layoutAlgorithm? Highcharts demo example looks example as your requirement.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/treemap-layoutalgorithm-sliceanddice/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: "treemap",
        data: [{
            name: 'A',
            value: 6
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            value: 6
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            value: 4
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            value: 3
        }, {
            name: 'E',
            value: 2
        }, {
            name: 'F',
            value: 2
        }, {
            name: 'G',
            value: 1
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.layoutAlgorithm

---

EDIT

After discussion - the best solution for this case is using the drilldown module mixed with treemap series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fo64ubLg/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown

Comment: I need this chart as treemap because I have some nested data I need to display when each tile is clicked

Comment: @GUDARI but it is a treemap chart.

Comment: I tried changing to sliceAndDice but the problem is now on nested tiles. You can see on this imgur https://imgur.com/a/40VggVd

Comment: @GUDARI sorry, but I have no idea what is going on this imgur. You have asked about treemap as shown in the image, I suggested the solution. Here is an output with your names: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/daLu6ywm/ There was no information about any nested tiles. If you need help with implementing them, please prepare the demo and ask another specific question.

Comment: @GUDARI Could you update jsfiddle example once again? It seems like it is the old one still.

Comment: @GUDARI Thank you. But do you want to display particular data after clicking to a particular tile? If yes, use the drilldown event to achieve it, because now this data is displaying on the main chart. Now it depends which output do you want to achieve. Something like is demonstrate in Highcharts official demo base: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset/ or if you want to keep the initial displaying use the drilldown module: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fo64ubLg/

Comment: I think the second option is the one who best fits to my requirements. If you edit your answer using this link I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks so much